# Track file transfer progress to know when file is done uploading

Tags: go

I have server that will receives files via scp, sftp to a specific folder.  Once the files are copied they will be ran through another tool that will get called by my program.  However, my problem is I need to ensure the files are finished transferring prior to the next step in the workflow.

I have code that reads my upload directory for new files.  Once a file is detected I run it through something like the following:

```
func getFileData(fileToUpload os.FileInfo) {
    var newSize int64
    var currentSize int64

    currentSize = 0
    newSize = 0
    
    for {
        currentSize = fileToUpload.Size()
        fmt.Printf("Current size= %v\n", currentSize)
        if currentSize != 0 {
            if currentSize > newSize {
                newSize = currentSize
                fmt.Printf("Current size= %v\n", currentSize)
                fmt.Printf("New size= %v\n", newSize)
            } else if newSize == currentSize {
                fmt.Printf("File %s, is done.\n", fileToUpload)
                break
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println(fileDone)
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is even though I am looping and a file is transferring currentSize stays at 0 and it never updates.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The logic here does not work at all. You need a real mechanism to indicate the upload is finished, or a very long timeout. For one, you might go 3 seconds without receiving additional data due to a variety of causes that may not mean the upload is complete; maybe network lag or connection interrupted. For another, it may block out the full known file size at the start of the upload, and then fill it with data as the upload progresses, in order to avoid fragmentation and reserve the disk space, so the file size won't change.

Comment: Also if you're not re-reading the `FileInfo`, it's never going to change anyway; you're just re-checking the same data you read once, instead of re-reading the current data each iteration.